# Get Angular2/4 Carousel from service to loop over images

Tags: angular, loops, service, carousel

I have a carousel in Angular. It is relatively simple to embed slide images in the html, but I want to insert them from an array in a service.

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <ul class="carousel-item active">
      <li *ngFor="let image of visibleImages" >
        <img src="{{image.url}}" class ="tn">
      </li>
    </ul>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

My ts for the component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageServiceService } from '../image-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-slider',
  templateUrl: './image-slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-slider.component.css']
})
export class ImageSliderComponent implements OnInit {
    visibleImages: any[] = [];

  constructor(private imageService: ImageServiceService) {
    this.visibleImages = this.imageService.getImages();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And my ts for the service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ImageServiceService {

    visibleImages = [];
    getImages(){
        return this.visibleImages = IMAGES.slice(0);
    }

    getImage(id: number){
            return IMAGES.slice(id).find(image => image.id === id);
    }

}

const IMAGES = [
    {"id": 1, "category": "paintings", "caption": "a painting", "url": '../assets/SBI_Slide_1.jpg'},
    {"id": 2, "category": "paintings", "caption": "a painting", "url": '../assets/Eagle_Slide_2.jpg'},
    {"id": 3, "category": "paintings", "caption": "a painting", "url": '../assets/Knot_Slide_3.jpg'},
];
```

First I want to loop over the images, instead of displaying them all at once. It might be good if there was a wait between stages of the loop?

Next I want to trigger going forward or backward through the loop with a method?

Comment: what is your problem ? is there any error ?

Comment: yes there is - this displays the images all at once, I want them to display one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-carousel). It should work for what you want to accomplish.

Edit:

Your slideshow could look something more like this, which is more modular and cleaner:

```
<div *ngFor="let slide of slides" [class.hide-slide]="!slide.selected" class="text-center slides margin-bottom">
  <app-slide
    [imageUrl]="slide.url"
    [slideTitle]="slide.title"
    [bodyText]="slide.body"
 ></app-slide>
</div>
```

Check out [this plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/Z8QPuD/) for an implementation I used based on [W3 Schools CSS slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp).

Comment: That's great and it looks like it does what I want in this case, but my goal is to become an Angular expert and I need to understand the structure of what is going on. It should only take a few lines of code to get Angular to only show the element of the array at index i